# How to access multivalue json output from extjs in yii

Tags: json, extjs, yii

i am working in extjs+yii framework. My client side is in extjs and server side design is in yii framework. So extjs's forms inputs are coming to yii framewok via json. This json is accepted in yii controller action as-

```
 public function actionSetUserAnswer()
              {
     $postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
                 $clientData = $postData['data'];
                  }
```

Actual json data send by extjs is-

```
'{"data":[{"optionId":"","questionId":"1","isAnswer":"","option":"Aus","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"2","isAnswer":"","option":"india","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"3","isAnswer":"","option":"England","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"4","isAnswer":"","option":"Srilanka","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null}]}';
```

So in yii how to access these individual fields of json like option,questionId etc using $clientdata variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use array subscripts

```
$option = $clientData[0]['option']
```

or

```
$questionId = $clientData[0]['questionId']
```

If you want to retrieve multiple values for use in `findByAttributes`, then you need an array of values. You first retrieve the `questionId`s from JSON

```
function get_question_id($elem) {
    return $elem['questionId'];
}

$questionIds = array_map('get_question_id', $clientData);
```

and then use this array in `findByAttributes`

```
$record=Question::model()->findByAttributes(array("questionId"=>$questionIds));
```

*Update* incorporating your last comment:

```
static public function get_question_id($elem)
{
    return $elem['questionId'];
}

public function actionSetUserAnswer() {
    $clientData = '{"data":[{"optionId":"","questionId":"1","isAnswer":"","option":"Au‌​s","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},...]}';
    $obj = json_decode($clientData['data']);
    $questionIds = array_map('get_question_id', $obj);
    var_dump($questionIds);
    $records = Question::model()->findByAttributes(array("questionId"=>$questionIds));
}
```

Comment: Thanx sir for reply..Actually sir i want to take each questionId from this json,then need to search record for this questionId from database. So i am using query as- $record=Question::model()->findByAttributes(array("questionId"=>$clientData[$i]['questionId'])); But its giving error at format of $clientData[$i]['questionId']. It is not accepting brackets. So how to access this json fields in yii framework.

Comment: i had tried as follows..i had written simple function as-         public function actionSetUserAnswer(){ $clientData='{"data":[{"optionId":"","questionId":"1","isAnswer":"","option":"Aus","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},{"optionId":"","questionId":"2","isAnswer":"","option":"india","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null}]}';
 $questionIds = $this->get_question_id($clientData);
 echo $questionIds;}} And in same controller i had written=   public function get_question_id($elem)
     {return $elem['questionId']; }  But its printing only '{' ,not any questionId

Comment: @user1636115 You have already set `$clientData = $postData['data']`. And you ignored the `array_map` part.

Comment: Actually sir there is some problem while sending data from extjs so i have taken direct json in $clientData.i had modified code as- public function actionSetUserAnswer(){ $clientData='{"data":[{"optionId":"","questionId":"1","isAnswer":"","option":"Aus","media":"","keyword":"","mediaTypeId":"","id":null},]}';
    $obj=json_decode($clientData);
     $record=$this->get_question_id($obj);
 $questionIds = array_map($record, $obj);var_dump($questionIds);
  echo $questionIds;
}   And  public function get_question_id($elem)
      {return $elem['questionId'];
      } But its not giving any questionId.

Comment: @user1636115 Please see my update. I used your comment code, as I think it should work to get the records with `findByAttributes`.